# Sorting an array (or list)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I have a loop and in this loop every time I get 3 different values, x, r, and c.

I want an array (I have tried using a list but I don't know how to sort it, searched a lot!) which will input the all the 3 values at each round of the loop in a new automatic index of the array, and at the end I want to sort this whole array based on ascending values (x, then r, and then c).

For example these are my values in an array getting added (I don't need a value for this array, these values (1,2,3) are the values, something like a table)

```
storage(1,2,3)
storage(2,3,4)
storage(3,4,5)
storage(4,5,6)
```

These 3 are actually co-ordinates of positions of a container in different stacks, and I want to find out which one is closer to the surface, and in a closer stack. Therefore I'm adding them into an array, and then I will sort them so I can find which one is closer (provided that all of these are matches for the same type of container, located at different places)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `.Sort()` method. It will use the `IComparable` interface implemented by each element of the `Array`. If you dont specify a custom comparer it will use the default, which is ok for `Integer` values.

Array:

```
Dim iNums() As Integer = New Integer() {1, 11, 7, 5}
Array.Sort(iNums)
```

List:

```
Dim aux As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {1, 11, 7, 5})
aux.Sort()
```

And if you need you can define you own comparer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.71).aspx